# Chrome not displaying H.264 video on startup

Tags: bash, xorg, google-chrome, video

I'm building a Kiosk using Ubuntu 14.04. I've followed [this tutorial](https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/). The web page I'm having Chrome go to contains an H.264 video, and when chrome opens the page, the video fails to load. It just displays a white page, not the first frame of the video or anything like that. For whatever reason, killing Chrome and restarting it will allow the video to play, but it's never on the first load of the page.

**First Script, located in `/opt`**

```
#!/bin/bash
xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
\#start-pulseaudio-x11
\#the following commands flip the screen and touch coordinates
xrandr --output VGA1 --rotate left -display :0.0
xinput set-prop "ILITEK ILITEK Multi-Touch" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
while true; do
    rm -rf ~/.{config,cache}/google-chrome/
    google-chrome --kiosk 'http://www.target-webpage.com'
done
```

**Second Script, located in `/etc/init`**

```
start on (started networking)
stop on runlevel [06]
console output
emits starting-x
respawn
exec sudo -u kioskdev startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --
```

So, the script located in `/etc/init` starts an xsession (openbox) and starts the script in `/opt`. The script in `/opt` starts Chrome and opens it on the target webpage. I have the flag `--kiosk` running so that the URL bar is inaccessible and the browser will default to fullscreen. When the second script opens chrome, all I see is a blank page, and the video doesn't play. However, if I navigate to the page manually, the video renders as it should.

How can I get it working the way I want?

Comment: Haved you look at the Chrome Dev Tools window (hit F12)

Comment: I didn't see anything when I looked earlier, although I'm away from the machine right now. I'll post another response tomorrow morning when I'm back in the office